# string literal - template conversion between char types

Tags: c++, templates, char, wchar-t

I would like to code a function that would look like:

```
template <typename CharT>
std::basic_string<CharT> convert(char const *);
```

and be used as follows:

```
convert<char>("Hello World!");     //  "Hello World!"
convert<wchar_t>("Hello World!");  // L"Hello World!"
convert<char16_t>("Hello World!"); // u"Hello World!"
convert<char32_t>("Hello World!"); // U"Hello World!"
```

I could use `std::codecvt` and co, but I find it almost pointless as it would be so easier to use some macro that adds `L`, `u` or `U` with 0 cost.

Unfortunately templates and macros don't act at the same level... So here comes my question: would there be some way to *mix* them ? Or is there a better way ?

My main goal is to avoid repetition (specialization) of code: some functions I'm coding are `CharT` templated and use string literals, and that would be the only difference. As an example:

```
template <typename CharT>
void foo (std::vector<std::basic_string<CharT>> const & vec, 
          std::basic_string<CharT> str = convert<CharT>("default"));
```

That would avoid to specialize foo() for each char type.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: I don't see the need for specialization here, just use e.g. `codecvt` with `char` as the "source" type and `CharT` as the "destination" type?

Comment: Indeed, I was already thinking about later. Edited, thanks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah but that's still runtime computation. The OP wants to avoid that since they're string literals and adding a certain prefix would do the trick.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't macros be the only way? I'm not certain, but I think the macro concatenation operator `##` can attach a prefix to a string constant. Unless this can be done with `operator""`? I doubt it though.

Comment: @celticminstrel The problem is that you can't have a macro that does different things depending on type, so you need to use multiple macros with different names, which seems to be what the OP wants to avoid. The only way I can see this being done is with a template function which unfortunately can't be `constexpr` (and therefore possible to evaluate at compile-time).

Comment: I already thought about such macros, but the problem is that they would be dependant of a template type, which is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: Use only one type of string literals (for example u8"default") and only one type of std::basic_string (for example std::string that contains utf8) all over your program logic. Then the problem stops existing itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the idea of using macros to generate every 4 overloads of the function foo.

```
template <typename CharT>
void foo (std::vector<std::basic_string<CharT>> const & vec, 
          std::basic_string<CharT> str = convert<CharT>("default"));
```

becomes

```
#define FOO(CharT, prefix) \
void foo (std::vector<std::basic_string<CharT>> const & vec, \
          std::basic_string<CharT> str = prefix ## "default");
```

and I just have to add

```
FOO(char, )
FOO(wchar_t, L)
FOO(char16_t, u)
FOO(char32_t, U)
```

four lines that I can also put into another macro GENERATE so I can simply call

```
GENERATE(FOO)
```

I know macros... but I've reached my main goal to avoid code repetition. :-)

Thanks everybody for your help!

## Update

After reading the paper [Formatting Ranges](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2286r6.html) and the mention of "*STATICALLY-WIDEN*", I finally have:

```
template <typename CharT>
constexpr auto statically_widen(
#ifdef __cpp_char8_t
    const char8_t * u8str,
#endif
    const char16_t* u16str,
    const char32_t* u32str,
    const char * str,
    const wchar_t* wstr
) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<CharT, char>::value)
        return str;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<CharT, wchar_t>::value)
        return wstr;
#ifdef __cpp_char8_t
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<CharT, char8_t>::value)
        return u8str;
#endif
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<CharT, char16_t>::value)
        return u16str;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<CharT, char32_t>::value)
        return u32str;
}

#ifdef __cpp_char8_t
    #define STATICALLY_WIDEN(CharT, str) statically_widen<CharT>(u8##str, u##str, U##str, str, L##str)
#else
    #define STATICALLY_WIDEN(CharT, str) statically_widen<CharT>(u##str, U##str, str, L##str)
#endif
```

```
template <typename CharT>
void foo (std::vector<std::basic_string<CharT>> const & vec, 
          std::basic_string<CharT> str = STATICALLY_WIDEN(CharT, "default"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: This will work from `C++11`. Since operator cannot be template you can change the operator overload to your `convert` function.

```
#include <string>

std::basic_string<char> operator ""_s(const char * str, std::size_t len) {
    return std::basic_string<char> (str, str + len);
}

std::basic_string<char16_t> operator ""_u(const char * str, std::size_t len) {
    return std::basic_string<char16_t> (str, str + len);
}

std::basic_string<char32_t> operator ""_U(const char * str, std::size_t len) {
    return std::basic_string<char32_t> (str, str + len);
}

std::basic_string<wchar_t> operator ""_L(const char * str, std::size_t len) {
    return std::basic_string<wchar_t> (str, str + len);
}


int main() {
    std::string s1    = "Hello World!"_s;
    std::u16string s2 = "Hello World!"_u;
    std::u32string s3 = "Hello World!"_U;
    std::wstring s4   = "Hello World!"_L;
    return 0;
}
```

See <kbd>[LIVE DEMO](https://ideone.com/HZheVX)</kbd> working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid that you would need to prefix the literals with `L`, `u` or `U` (exactly what I want to avoid). Here you are only generating std::basic_string<char>s.

Comment: @JemCpp I won't need to prefix anything, only suffix a `s` or `_s`.

Comment: Have a look at [this ideone](https://ideone.com/4Q1ptE) and [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) : parameters are `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`, not only `char`.

Comment: Ok, there is an improvement in your edited code, but still a problem : this doesn't produce the same Xstring. Make a comparison between `std::wstring(L"Jérémy")` and `"Jérémy"_L` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/YhVYg4))
I may though accomodate with it as I have very few chances of using accents or particular characters.